# Why My Solr Scores are all from 0.1 to 1?

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 5.3.0. I did some search and made the qf like "business^20, address^2, person^10". And I put "*,score" in fl field. I expected to see the difference of the document scores. But the scores were only shown as 0.1, 0.5 and 1.0. I did some search online, and I saw most people had different score that great than 1. So there must be some setting that was changed in my Solr. But I cannot find it. Anyone has any idea? Thank you!

Comment: The absolute values of scores are irrelevant and not comparable across different collections and their queries. You can use debugQuery to see how the score is calculated for each document in the query.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute values of scores are irrelevant and not comparable across different collections and their queries (so you can't compare the scores you're getting with the scores you've found other mentioning on the internet).

You can use debugQuery to see how the score is calculated for each document in the query, including each separate part that affects the score (number of documents, documents with a hit, term frequency, etc.) and how they're included in the score (additive, multiplicative).